# (C#) Improving speed of custom getBetweenAll

Tags: c#, string, performance, indexof

I've written a custom extension method in c# that is an improvement of the extensionmethod string[] getBetweenAll(string source, string startstring, string endstring);

Originally this extensionmethod found all substrings between two strings, for example:

```
string source = "<1><2><3><4>";
source.getBetweenAll("<", ">");
//output: string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
```

But if you had another occurrence of < in the beginning it would just get between that and the whole string

```
string source = "<<1><2><3><4>";
source.getBetweenAll("<", ">");
//output: string[] {"<1><2><3><4"}
```

So I re-wrote it to be more exact and search backwards from ">" to find the first occurrence of "<"

Now I got it working, but the problem here is that it is **way too slow** because the search method skips back *every character* of the whole string for each occurrence. Do you know how I could improve the speed of this function? Or is it not possible?

Here is the entire code so far http://pastebin.com/JEZmyfSG
I've added comments where the code needs speed improvement

```
public static List<int> IndexOfAll(this string main, string searchString)
{
    List<int> ret = new List<int>();
    int len = searchString.Length;
    int start = -len;
    while (true)
    {
        start = main.IndexOf(searchString, start + len);
        if (start == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.Add(start);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static string[] getBetweenAll(this string main, string strstart, string strend, bool preserve = false)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    List<int> ends = main.IndexOfAll(strend);
    foreach (int end in ends)
    {
        int start = main.previousIndexOf(strstart, end);  //This is where it has to search the whole source string every time
        results.Add(main.Substring(start, end - start) + (preserve ? strend : string.Empty));
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}

//This is the slow function (depends on main.Length)
public static int previousIndexOf(this string main, string find, int offset)
{
    int wtf = main.Length ;
    int x = main.LastIndexOf(find, wtf);
    while (x > offset)
    {
        x = main.LastIndexOf(find, wtf);
        wtf -= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

**I suppose another way of doing PreviousIndexOf(string, int searchfrom); would improve the speeds.. Like IndexOf() except backwards and with supplied start offset**

Comment: Yes, but it is interesting!

Comment: Can this maybe be made faster with a compiled Regex (e.g. `<([^>]*)>`)?

Comment: What is slow for you and what results you are expecting to be ok ?

Comment: Micro optimizations man here!  You could try  changing `ends` to an array and iterate over it with `for (int i = 0 etc` and pass the expected maximum size of `results` to the List constructor for `results`.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the original GetBetweenAll, we can use a regular expression. To match only the shortest "inner" appearances of the enclosing strings, we have to use a negative lookahead on the start string and a non-greedy quantifier for the content.

```
public static string[] getBetweenAll(this string main, 
    string strstart, string strend, bool preserve = false)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    string regularExpressionString = string.Format("{0}(((?!{0}).)+?){1}", 
        Regex.Escape(strstart), Regex.Escape(strend));
    Regex regularExpression = new Regex(regularExpressionString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var matches = regularExpression.Matches(main);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        if (preserve)
        {
            results.Add(match.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You should give the text you are using for actual testing and make clear what you expect. This works as per your explanation in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple method which is four times faster than yours (but without the `preserve` argument till now):

```
public static string[] getBetweenAll2(this string main, string strstart, string strend, bool preserve = false)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    int lenStart = strstart.Length;

    int indexStart = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        indexStart = main.IndexOf(strstart, indexStart);
        if (indexStart < 0)
            break;

        int indexEnd = main.IndexOf(strend, indexStart);

        if (indexEnd < 0)
            break;

        results.Add(main.Substring(indexStart+ lenStart, indexEnd- indexStart- lenStart));
        indexStart = indexEnd;
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

This gives you the numbers `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` out of your string `<1><2><3><4>`

Does this do what you want?

**[Edit]**

Finds nested things:

```
public static string[] getBetweenAll2(this string main, string strstart, string strend, bool preserve = false)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    int lenStart = strstart.Length; 
    int lenEnd = strend.Length;

    int index = 0;

    Stack<int> starPos = new Stack<int>();

    while (true)
    {
        int indexStart = main.IndexOf(strstart, index);
        int indexEnd = main.IndexOf(strend, index);

        if (indexStart != -1 && indexStart < indexEnd)
        {
            index = indexStart + lenStart;
            starPos.Push(index);
        }
        else if (indexEnd != -1 && (indexEnd < indexStart || indexStart == -1))
        {
            if (starPos.Count == 1)
            {
                int startOfInterst = starPos.Pop();
                results.Add(main.Substring(startOfInterst, indexEnd - startOfInterst));
            } else if(starPos.Count>0)
            {
                starPos.Pop();
            }
            index = indexEnd + lenEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Not really, it's faster but it's prints out weird results when i try to grab things.

it should search behind the end, let's say ".mp4" until it reaches the first occurrence of "http://" to avoid getting like "http://" from the start of the entire string and everything inbetween.. it's really hard to explain but I hope you understand

Comment: @Ragnar then show some actual example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using stack. As soon as you see opening token, start adding characters to the [stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx). As soon as you see closing token - pop everything from your stack and it will be your characters of interest.

Now once you have base case implemented, you can improve it to work using recursion. If you see another opening token before closing token - start collecting characters to new stack until you see a closing token.

This will give you complexity of O(N) since you need to pass all content only once.

You will also need to handle the case if you see closing token before the opening token, but it is not clear from your question what program should do then.

Comment: The thing is, it needs to do it backwards from each occurance of ">"

Comment: This does not change a thing - now your opening token is ">" and you go from end of the string to beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this does what I want, but in another way! A function that does PreviousIndexOf(string source, string token, int offset) would still be greatly appreciated for other stuff!

```
public static List<string> GetBetweenAll(this string main, string start, string finish, bool preserve = false,  int index = 0)
{
    List<string> matches = new List<string>();
    Match gbMatch = new Regex(Regex.Escape(start) + "(.+?)" + Regex.Escape(finish)).Match(main, index);
    while (gbMatch.Success)
    {
        matches.Add((preserve ? start : string.Empty) + gbMatch.Groups[1].Value + (preserve ? finish : string.Empty));
        gbMatch = gbMatch.NextMatch();
    }
    return matches;
}
public static string[] getBetweenAllBackwards(this string main, string strstart, string strend, bool preserve = false)
{
    List<string> all = Reverse(main).GetBetweenAll(Reverse(strend), Reverse(strstart), preserve);
    for (int i = 0; i < all.Count; i++)
    {
        all[i] = Reverse(all[i]);
    }
    return all.ToArray();
}
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```