# Get Shortest String between two Words C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I want to get the shortest string between two given words. I can get the string between two words, but the problem happens if there is same word twice.

Sentence: The **people** who were working with other **people** are here.

I want to get the string between the last **people** and **here**.
This is the method I am currently using:

```
private static string Between(this string value, string a, string b)
{
    int posA = value.IndexOf(a);
    int posB = value.LastIndexOf(b);
    if (posA == -1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (posB == -1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    int adjustedPosA = posA + a.Length;
    if (adjustedPosA >= posB)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return value.Substring(adjustedPosA, posB - adjustedPosA);
}
```

This function works if there is no repeat. But for the example it returns me all the string between the first people and here. How can I get the result between the last people and here? The result I am expecting is **are**.

Comment: Your question does not match its title. A "string between two shortest words" and  a "shortest string between two words" are completely different things.

Comment: Aren't `the`, `who` and `and` the shortest words in the sentence?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, Question updated. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @DeanOC, sorry for my bad English. Question is now updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LastIndexOf` When looking for both words, so that you always find the last occurence of the word.

```
   int posA = value.LastIndexOf(a);
   int posB = value.LastIndexOf(b);
```

However: this might not produce what you want for "The people who were working here with other people". Please clarify your requirements

Other Solution using regular expressions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35105389/101087